# SymPy: Swap two variables

Tags: python, sympy

In an expression like

```
import sympy

a = sympy.Symbol('a')
b = sympy.Symbol('b')

x = a + 2*b
```

I'd like to swap `a` and `b` to retrieve `b + 2*a`. I tried

```
y = x.subs([(a, b), (b, a)])
y = x.subs({a: b, b: a})
```

but neither works; the result is `3*a` in both cases as `b`, for some reason, gets replaced first.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `simultaneous` argument you can pass to the substitution, which will ensure that all substitutions happen simultaneously and don't interfere with one another as they are doing now.

```
y = x.subs({a:b, b:a}, simultaneous=True)
```

**Outputs**:

```
2*a + b
```

---

[From the docs for `subs`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs):

> If the keyword `simultaneous` is `True`, the subexpressions will not be evaluated until all the substitutions have been made.